# Correlated subquery SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, correlated-subquery

[image: In the following picture showing two tables and a SQL query.]

The question of this assignment: what will be the result of the query?

I know the answer, but I don't really understand how the SQL query works, especially in the row, which I marked with question mark.

So far, I realized that first we [join two tables from subquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbCL3.png)

SQL query:

```
select Count(*)  
from OrderDetails as OD 
inner join [Order] as O on OD.idOrder = O.id  
where SalePrice = all (select Price  
                       from OrderDetails 
                       inner join [Order] on OrderDetails.idOrder = [Order].id  
                       where idCustomer != O.idCustomer 
                         and OrderDetails.idProduct = OD.idProduct)
```

Comment: What's the database engine? Looks like SQL Server.

Comment: In the task it is not specified which database engine is it.

Comment: apart from the quoting of identifiers and non standard not equals operator this is standard SQL. It is not necessary to know to answer the question.

Comment: In your example, unless your subquery returns just 1 record with a SalePrice that exists in your main query, you will not get a data back. This is because of the operator preceeding ALL ('='). A really nice illustration on ALL can be found here: https://www.w3resource.com/sql/special-operators/sql_all.php

Comment: Tip: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Answer (score 2):

As a *logical* description first start by expanding out the join as this is used both by the outer query and the sub query.

[image]

The first row in the image above has `idCustomer` of `1` and `idProduct` of `1`. The subquery is looking for all rows with the same product id and different customerid. For the first row there are two rows matching this combination (highlighted yellow in both columns). These are the ones with the `Price` column highlighted red below.

[image]

The `SalePrice` column from the outer row has a value of `1`. This is the same as all of the red highlighted `Price` values (i.e. none of them have a different value) so the first outer row meets the `= ALL` predicate and contributes to the count.

The same process is repeated for the remaining 9 rows returned by the join.